# What is wrong with FileRepo? All is added but I can't use anything

Tags: python

from Exception.Exceptions import *
import re

class Repo(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__items_dictionary = {}

def get_element(self, id):
    try:
        return self.__items_dictionary[id]
    except KeyError:
        raise RepositoryError("ID not existent")

def add_item(self, new_item):
    try:
        if new_item.id in self.__items_dictionary.keys():
            raise RepositoryError("Id already exists!")
        self.__items_dictionary[new_item.id] = new_item
    except AttributeError:
        raise RepositoryError('Element does not have an id introduced!')

def remove_item(self, id):
    try:
        if id in self.__items_dictionary.keys():
            return self.__items_dictionary.pop(id)
        else:
            raise RepositoryError("Element does not exist!")
    except KeyError:
        raise RepositoryError("Element with that id does not exist!")

def update_item(self, id, attribute, new_value):
    if id in self.__items_dictionary.keys():
        if hasattr(self.__items_dictionary[id], attribute):
            setattr(self.__items_dictionary[id], attribute, new_value)
        else:
            raise RepositoryError("Element with that attribute does not exist!")
    else:
        raise RepositoryError('Element with that id does not exist!')

def search_item(self, attribute, search_value):
    searched_items = []
    try:
        if attribute == 'id':
            search_value = int(search_value)
            if search_value in self.__items_dictionary.keys():
                searched_items.append(self.__items_dictionary[search_value])
        else:
            search_value = search_value.lower()
            for item in self.__items_dictionary.keys():
                item_string = getattr(self.__items_dictionary[item], attribute).lower()
                if re.findall(search_value, item_string):
                    searched_items.append(self.__items_dictionary[item])
        return searched_items
    except ValueError as ve:
        raise RepositoryError(ve)

@property
def get_all(self):
    return self.__items_dictionary

def get_all_for_file(self):
    return self.__items_dictionary
```

class FileRepository(Repo):

```
def __init__(self,filename, read_entity, write_entity):
    Repo.__init__(self)
    self.__filename = filename
    self.__read_entity = read_entity
    self.__write_entity = write_entity

def _read_all_from_file(self):
    self._entities = {}
    with open(self.__filename,'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            if line != "":
                entity = self.__read_entity(line)
                self._entities[entity.id] = entity


def _write_all_to_file(self):
    with open(self.__filename, 'w') as file:
        for entity in self._entities:
            line = self.__write_entity(entity)
            file.write(line + "\n")

def add_item(self,new_item):
    self._read_all_from_file()
    Repo.add_item(self, new_item)
    self._write_all_to_file()

def search_item(self, attribute, search_value):
    self._read_all_from_file()
    return Repo.search_item(self, attribute,search_value)

def update_item(self, id, attribute, new_value):
    self._read_all_from_file()
    Repo.update_item(self, id,attribute,new_value)
    self._write_all_to_file()

def remove_item(self, id):
    self._read_all_from_file()
    Repo.remove_item(self, id)
    self._write_all_to_file()

def get_all(self):
    self._read_all_from_file()
    return Repo.get_all

def get_element(self, id):
    self._read_all_from_file()
    return Repo.get_element(self,id)
```

I have checked and all gets added to it but whenever I try to access anything I get something like 'function' object has no attribute 'values' or 'method' object is not iterable. Could it be that I am calling that @property? But even when I tried with get_all_for_file() it still did't work...

Comment: This has so much wrong that it deserves a better answer than I can write.